# xapian and django-haystack

Tags: django, xapian, django-haystack

I have a problem with django-haystack. According [to this tutorial](http://tartarus.org/james/diary/2009/10/20/simple-search-for-django-using-haystack-and-xapian) I got this apps:
 django-haystack
 xapian-haystack

I set everything but i have this error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'xapian' isn't an available search backend. Available options are: 'dummy', 'solr', 'whoosh'

Why xapian is not available?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok, i found a solution:) here http://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xapian isn't included with Haystack due to licensing differences. You have to get the xapian backend from http://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack.

Answer (score 1):

To install xapian, you may need xapian and xapian-bindings. So now, you just have to install xapian-haystack with :

```
pip install xapian-haystack
```

or

```
easy_install xapian-haystack
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't think that xapian is included with any of these python libraries.  they only allow you to leverage xapian from python code.  you need to install xapian itself first.

see more here: http://xapian.org/